# Maximum number of websockets that can be opened on a server

Tags: tcp, websocket, load-balancing, benchmarking

I have simple web socket node server as follows:

```
var ws = require("nodejs-websocket")
var connectionCount = 0;
console.info("Node websocket started @ 8002");

var server = ws.createServer(function (conn) {;
    console.log("New connection", ++connectionCount);
    conn.on("close", function (code, reason) {
        console.log("Connection closed")
    });
}).listen(8002);
```

How many web socket connections can we make on this server from DIFFERENT clients? By different client, I mean browsers from different computers across the world.

And what are the things to consider while building such web socket servers and what are the load testing tools to do some bench marking?

Comment: For benchmarking there is only one rule: benchmark it. Otherwise this depends on the OS and this and that and I'm sure you're not happy with just having open connections that don't do anything so each case is different.

Comment: There is no intrinsic limit, just memory, threads, socket handles, resources in general, all of which depend on your local configuration of your specific operating system. @closevoters This is not 'too broad'. Just unanswerable.

Comment: There's no way to answer your question given the amount of information you've included.  A properly configured and optimized server can handle hundreds of thousands of simultaneous sockets.  A Google search for millions of socket connections will give you a set of articles.